# Showing primes can be of the form $16x^2+y^2$

Tags: number-theory

Hello everyone I am trying to solve a question that involving primes. Show that all primes that are of the form 1 more than a multiple of 8 can be written in the form $16x^2 + y^2$. I am given the theorem that a prime number can be represented by the sum of two perfect square if and only if $p$ is of the form 1 more than a multiple of 4.

I have been doing a lot of algebra in this question with little avail. I would really appreciate some help with this question. It's not a homework question (well it is but I am not getting marked for it)  but I just want some guidance. Thank you!

Comment: It might have something to do with Fermat's 2 square theorem

Comment: Can you expand a little more? Isn't that the idea that given a prime that is of the form $4n + 1$ then it can be written by the sum of two perfect squares?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every prime of the form $4k+1$ is a sum of two squares. In particular, every prime of form $8k+1$ is a sum of two squares.

Now, consider $x^2+y^2 \bmod 8$. Because the only squares mod $8$ are $0$, $1$, and $4$, if you consider all cases mod $8$, you'll see that you'll only get $x^2+y^2 \equiv 1 \bmod 8$ when $x$ or $y$ is a multiple of $4$. If $x=4z$ then of course $x^2+y^2 = 16z^2+y^2$, as required.

Reciprocally, if a prime can be written as $16x^2+y^2$, then it is of the form $8k+1$ because mod $8$ it is of the form $y^2$ and it cannot be even.

Comment: What does "the only squares mod 8 are 0,1 and 4" mean? Do you mean they're divisible by 8?

Comment: @qwr, it means that $t^2 \equiv 0,1,4 \bmod 8$ for all $t$.

Comment: Thank you for that very simple solution. I often make these problems a lot more complicated then it needed to be. Funny I actually knew it must also be the sum of two squares but I tried to do a lot of messy algebra. This is for a problem solving class so I am still getting used to of looking at these interesting problems!